# Python not finding Tesseract command

Tags: python, osx-elcapitan, python-tesseract

I've installed Tesseract with homebrew and on command line it works fine, ex:

```
tesseract "image.jpg" output.txt
```

but when I try to use it in conjunction with a python tesseract wrapper like textract or pytesseract, I get this error:

```
textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command `tesseract "captcha.jpg"
/var/folders/1k/30brhf2n2y7ct_z7rhgtm9qr0000gn/T/tmpcFy9Sk > 
/dev/null && cat /var/folders/1k/30brhf2n2y7ct_z7rhgtm9qr0000gn/T/tmpcFy9Sk.txt && 
rm -f /var/folders/1k/30brhf2n2y7ct_z7rhgtm9qr0000gn/T/tmpcFy9Sk /var/folders/1k/30brhf2n2y7ct_z7rhgtm9qr0000gn/T/tmpcFy9Sk.txt` 
failed because the executable
`tesseract` is not installed on your system. Please make
sure the appropriate dependencies are installed before using textract
```

when I try:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["tesseract", "image.jpg", "output.txt"])
```

I get error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

brew info tesseract returns:

```
tesseract: stable 3.04.01 (bottled), HEAD
OCR (Optical Character Recognition) engine
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1 (76 files, 38.8M) *
Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-        core/blob/master/Formula/tesseract.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: leptonica ✔
Recommended: libtiff ✔
```

Comment: There is a python wrapper for tesseract, why not use that?

Comment: What happens if you try `call(["tesseract", "image.jpg", "output.txt"], shell=True)`?

Comment: @Harry I get `image.jpg tesseract: command not found`. It works if I use the full path `call(["/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/bin/tesseract", "image.jpg", "output.txt"])`